# Trying to UPDATE cells in Excel 2010 2013 using ACE.OLEDB.12.0 but only 1st row is updating

Tags: c#, connection-string, oledb, excel-2010, oledbconnection

I am trying to update an individual cell in excel, following code perfectly works on excel 2007 and I dont even need to install AccessDatabaseEngine! its working as it should! but when I run the code on Excel 2010 or 2013. First row only updating by last row data! for example if I wanted to update 10 row in cell A, Only A1 would be updated by data which supposed to be store in A10!

I assume  ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver have some bug. I hope anyone already fixed the issue share the solution here.

Bear in mind that I already installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe and tried with both version 2007 and 2010 and getting same result!

I am kind of stock in this for few month I really appreciate if someone can help!

```
void my(){
        string filelink = "C:\\test.xlsx";
        try
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

            string sql = null;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filelink + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\"");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;




             sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1 = '" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "'";
             myCommand.CommandText = sql;
             myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

             sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$B1:B1] SET F1 = '" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "'";
             myCommand.CommandText = sql;
             myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

             sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$B2:B2] SET F1 = '" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "'";
             myCommand.CommandText = sql;
             myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
             MyConnection.Close();           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> As you are invoking/executing multiple update commands please ensure
>   that at the end of every update everything is cleared properly. i have
>   modified your code by creating one more new method which will take the file
>   link and sqlcommand string to be executed as parameters.
>
> this functions main responsibility is to invoking the given command
>   and dispose the all connection and command objects properly so that
>   next command can be invoked with out any trouble.

```
void my()
            {
                string filelink = "C:\\test.xlsx";

                sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1 = '" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "'";
                ExecuteMyCommand(filelink,sql);

                sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$B1:B1] SET F1 = '" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "'";
                ExecuteMyCommand(filelink,sql);

                sql = "UPDATE[sheet1$B2:B2] SET F1 = '" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "'";
                ExecuteMyCommand(filelink,sql);

            }

            private void ExecuteMyCommand(String filelink,String sql)
            {
     using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection =
                        new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filelink +";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\""))
                {
                     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
                     MyConnection.Open();
                     myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
                     myCommand.CommandText = sql;
                     myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: cheers mate! You are right about cleared property I changed my code as you suggested but I still having same issue! any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issues for HOURS. After much researching to no avail, I found that the only way I could update specific cells was by doing an INSERT...even though there was already existing data and I merely needed to update. Try this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO[sheet1$B2:B2] VALUES ('" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "')"
```